# rails render_to_string partial in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, render, partial

How can i render partial to string and assign content to my model attribute?

I now that is not by MVC convetion, but it's easier to predefine some content then

assign same thing from controller to controller

THanks

Answer (score 0):

you should create a helper for that.

A helper is here to provide your views and controllers with those kind of things. It allows your controller to stay thin. And your model to stay a model.

I once included a render_as_html into a model. And it was ugly.